# DKIM error when sending mail with GSuite using PHP Mailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, google-workspace, dkim

I am hosted at A2 hosting, but I am using GSuite to handle all my mail.

When I send test message to mail-tester.com from Gmail I get an awesome rating.

However when I sent a message using my PHP script:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
ob_start();

//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                 // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                             // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = $pickuploc . '@xxxx.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'xxx';  
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;   // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 587;                              // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom($pickuploc . '@xxx.com', 'xxx xxxx');
$mail->addAddress($email, $fname . " " . $lname);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addBCC($pickuploc . '@xxx.com');

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
include 'email-confirmed.html';
$mail->Subject = 'Your Reservation Has Been Confirmed!';
$mail->Body    = ob_get_clean();
$mail->AltBody = 'Your reservation has been confirmed.';

$mail->send();
```

I get an error from mail-tester.com that reads my DKIM is not valid.

I think this is because I am sending form a foreign server (not Google) and my MX records point to Google, but I really need these emails to get though, how should I work this problem?

Is there a way to configure this in PHP Mailer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's complaining is because you're not signing with DKIM at all!

You can do DKIM signing with PHPMailer, but there's a certain amount of setup required. PHPMailer provides some code to help you do this. Make sure you're using [PHPMailer 6.1.1 or later](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer); older versions have bugs affecting DKIM signing.

First of all you need to [create your DKIM keys](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/DKIM_gen_keys.phps) and put them in your DNS.

Now you need to alter your script to sign messages using your private key, as shown in [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/DKIM_sign.phps); the parts you need to add are:

```php
//This should be the same as the domain of your From address
$mail->DKIM_domain = 'example.com';
//See the DKIM_gen_keys.phps script for making a key pair -
//here we assume you've already done that.
//Path to your private key:
$mail->DKIM_private = 'dkim_private.pem';
//Set this to your own selector
$mail->DKIM_selector = 'phpmailer';
//Put your private key's passphrase in here if it has one
$mail->DKIM_passphrase = '';
//The identity you're signing as - usually your From address
$mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;
//Suppress listing signed header fields in signature, defaults to true for debugging purpose
$mail->DKIM_copyHeaderFields = false;
//Optionally you can add extra headers for signing to meet special requirements
$mail->DKIM_extraHeaders = ['List-Unsubscribe', 'List-Help'];
```

Comment: I have no idea how to get the DKIM private key or any of that from G Suite - could you assist?

Comment: That link states Google does not give out the private key, so how would I go about setting this up to work with GSuite?

Comment: Follow the first link - you need to create your own keys and put them your own DNS for your domain. You don’t need google‘S keys.

Comment: I follow the instructions exactly, I generated the public and private keys with the script given on my server, but when I try to test it with https://tools.sparkpost.com/dkim I get an error of "Failed Signature could not be verified" Help?

Comment: There are some DKIM issues in 6.1 that I'm working on at the moment, keep an eye out for a new release soon.